# Graph Tool installation problems

Tags: python, dependencies, libraries

I am trying to install python graph tool on ubuntu 16.04 .

I tried both paths suggested here https://graph-tool.skewed.de/download#packages:

1. manual installation using `.\configure` `make` `make install`
2. pre-compiled packages and `apt-get install python-graph-tool`

The manual installation has lots of problem in the `make` phase.

The second path (that is also the suggested one) gives me the following error:

```
sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install python-graph-tool
[sudo] password for riccardo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-graph-tool : Depends: libboost-iostreams1.58.0 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libboost-python1.58.0 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libboost-regex1.58.0 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libboost-graph1.58.0 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libboost-system1.58.0 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libboost-thread1.58.0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I run `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` I get :

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libboost-all-dev is already the newest version (1.61.0.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
```

And If i try to install each single package by hand, I obtain for example:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-coroutine1.58.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libboost-coroutine1.58.0 is not available, but is referred to by  another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libboost-coroutine1.58.0' has no installation candidate
```

I am new to both python and Linux. Can you help me to figure out what is going wrong in here?

Many Thanks

Comment: @anx I gave u all the info u asked for. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the missing packages in the Ubuntu package index for `xenial-updates` ([example](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libboost-iostreams1.58.0)) and download them for your architecture. Then install them with your favourite package manager. On the the command line that could be:

```
sudo apt install libboost*_$(dpkg --print-architecture).deb
```

Answer (score 0):

It says in the documentation that DISTRIBUTION can be any of

```
xenial, yakkety, zesty
```

I got the same error as you did with `zesty`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-graph-tool : Depends: libboost-iostreams1.62.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-python1.62.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-regex1.62.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-graph1.62.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-system1.62.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-thread1.62.0 but it is not installable
                      Recommends: python3-matplotlib but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

, but no problems when trying out `xenial`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gdebi-core libgles1-mesa linux-headers-4.4.0-62 linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72 linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-lyx libboost-context1.58.0 libboost-coroutine1.58.0 libboost-graph1.58.0 libboost-python1.58.0 libcgal11v5 libjs-jquery-ui
  python-matplotlib-data python3-cycler python3-dateutil python3-decorator python3-matplotlib python3-numpy python3-pyparsing python3-scipy
  python3-tk python3-tz ttf-bitstream-vera
Suggested packages:
  libjs-jquery-ui-docs ffmpeg ipython3 python-matplotlib-doc python3-cairocffi python3-gobject python3-nose python3-pyqt4 python3-sip
  python3-tornado ttf-staypuft gfortran python-numpy-doc python3-dev python3-numpy-dbg python-scipy-doc tix python3-tk-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-lyx libboost-context1.58.0 libboost-coroutine1.58.0 libboost-graph1.58.0 libboost-python1.58.0 libcgal11v5 libjs-jquery-ui
  python-matplotlib-data python3-cycler python3-dateutil python3-decorator python3-graph-tool python3-matplotlib python3-numpy python3-pyparsing
  python3-scipy python3-tk python3-tz ttf-bitstream-vera
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
Need to get 51.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 247 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  python3-graph-tool
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] Y
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above try to change the distribution

deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://downloads.skewed.de/apt DISTRIBUTION main

of the options on the page (bullseye, buster, sid, bionic, eoan, focal, groovy), only "focal" worked correctly.

Comment: It's unclear what you're suggesting - is this an edit to `/etc/apt/sources.list`? If yes, please format it accordingly, and be precise.